# Calling footer links in child template file of footer

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, page-content

I have `local.xml` like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
        <default> 
            <reference name="footer">
                <block type="core/template" name="footerblock" template="footerblock.phtml" >
                <block type="core/template" name="copyright" template="copyright.phtml" />
            </reference>

        </default>
    </layout>
```

So in the footer, I can access child templates `footer.phtml`,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footerblock'); ?> 
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('copyright'); ?>
```

And I can access footer links in `footer.phtml` file, but how can I access it in `footerblock.phtml` file like this?

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links'); ?>
```

Comment: you need to make footer_links a child of footerblock, and not of footer

Answer (score 1):

Add path file page/template

```
<block type="core/template" name="footerblock" template="page/template/footerblock.phtml" >
<block type="core/template" name="copyright" template="page/template/copyright.phtml" />
```

**or**

**U can direct access this code on footer file:**

> getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/footerblock.phtml')->toHtml();

Answer (score 0):

Use this in footerblock.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_links')->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: this code call for cmsblock not page core template file.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add this at footer then footer_links  should called as file

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <layout>
            <default> 
                <reference name="footer">
                    <block type="core/template" name="footerblock" template="footerblock.phtml" >

                    <block type="core/template" name="copyright" template="copyright.phtml" />
 <!-- add this -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="footer_links" />
                </reference>

            </default>
    </layout>
```

As `cms/block` block is `not need to  define` it `template file` so i am not added template
now you need to `juct call at footer.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links'); ?>
```